Routing for application from inside subdirectory
I am quite new to coldbox. I haven't been able to find proper answer from google, so throwing the question out here.
I am working with ColdFusion 2021 and Coldbox 7.0
Below is my folder structure
wwwroot
   |--app
       |--v1

v1 folder is where I executed the coldbox command

coldbox create app name=myproject skeleton=rest

Now when I try to access http://localhost:8500/app/v1/ from postman, it goes to defaultEvent configured in my Coldbox.cfc.
Now for any other handlers, I am having problem defining route. Even the default /healthcheck url (http://localhost:8500/app/v1/healthcheck) is not working.
Below is the snippet of healtcheck url in my Router.cfc
route( "/healthcheck", function( event, rc, prc ){
        return "Ok!";
    } );

I have also tried adding below code in configure function in my Router.cfc
setBaseURL("application/v6");

This also didn't help.
Any suggestion will be very helpful.
